# vim-fugitive doesn't show whitespace changes

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

I'm using vim-fugitive's `:Gdiff` for commits, but it doesn't show whitespace changes, so I can't commit, for example, indentation changes. I don't have any global git configs like `core.whitespace`, and if I run `git diff` in the shell I see whitespace changes.

Any ideas how to make fugitive's diff mode ws-sensitive?

Thanks.

Comment: Thats weird, `:Gdiff` shows white space changes for me. I don't have any custom settings.

Comment: @Atri I certainly don't have any whitespace settings in my global `.gitconfig`, is there any othe config files that I should be checking?

Comment: Probably what you could try is remove the vim config file and check. Then you can remove other vim plugins one by one and see if it works. This way  you might be able to pinpoint on which plugin is causing the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Atri guessed, the problem was with my `.vimrc`. I had this line:

```
set diffopt=filler,iwhite
```

`iwhite` part is causing diff mode to ignore whitespace changes. Removing that fixes this problem.